# Trying to do a simple SQL table to HTML table example using SQLSRV

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Majority of the examples I saw online assume you know the specific column to output. But what if you don't? Here's what I got so far using SQLSRV

The question is: what if I want to display all of an SQL table into an HTML table, making the columns the header and the rest of the data rows?

```
            <?php
            $serverName = "serverName\instanceName";
            $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password");
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
            if( $conn === false ) {
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable";
            $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
            if( $stmt === false) {
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
            }

            echo "<table>";
            echo "<thead>";
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach (sqlsrv_fetch_field($stmt) as $column){
                echo "<th>$column</th>";
            }
            echo "</tr></thead>";
            echo "<tbody>";
            echo "<tr>";                
            while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                echo "<td>$row</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";

            echo "</tbody></table>";

            sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
            ?>
```

Comment: What's your question? What's not working? Errors? Undesired output?

Comment: do you want to print out _all_ columns and you just don't know what they're called? Then [Show Columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html) might be the thing you're looking for.

Comment: or you want to have a indexed array with `sql_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)` -> [sql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/de/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php)

Comment: or you want `foreach($row as $col) { echo $col; }` (when staying with `SQLSRC_FETCH_ASSOC`)

Comment: The question is: what if I want to display all of an SQL table into an HTML table, making the columns the header and the rest of the data rows?